# FCM push notification to android 8.0 , custom sound not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When push notification to Android 8.0 App run in background , custom sound not working.

sound path : app/src/main/res/raw/siren_noise.wav

```
{

    "to" : "devices token",

    "notification" : {

        "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
        "title": "Title of Your Notification",
        "sound": "siren_noise",
        "android_channel_id": "7373737"

     }

}
```

Comment: you have to set  Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound); and     notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build()); in your Android code. And also check http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-way-to-send-local-notification-to-user-in-android and https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: Can i when receive notification sound is based on server push json sound name play the sound? Coz your code is custom notification not default notification.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the firebase messaging official sample to set custom details to your notification, custom default icon, custom default color and sound

[Firebase Cloud Messaging Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/README.md)

Comment: I have try download the project and add custom sound, but still not working on 8.0, only not working on 8.0